# need help installing AptUrl or changing the enviromental variable

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, environment-variables

I understand how to get the file to install, I have to type out "sudo apt-get install apturl" and it should open the package for installation.

I type out the command and I got this

```
"mspyellow@BJ:~$ sudo apt-get install apturl
Command 'sudo' is available in '/usr/bin/sudo'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable."
```

Then I typed it out using "/sudo" at the end and i ended up with this

```
"mspyellow@BJ:~$ usr/bin/sudo apt-get install apturl
bash: usr/bin/sudo: No such file or directory"
```

What is it that I need to do so I can install Apturl. Or how can I change the path so I dont have to put "/usr/bin/" because I didn't have to put that before i installed JDK7.

Thanks in advance for the suggestion and help... I am a beginner, so sorry if this are retarded questions

Comment: Please add the output of `echo $PATH$` to your question via [edit]

Answer (score 1):

Did you change a system file? Normally, the PATH variable should be set correctly...

However, in your second try, you forgot the starting slash. The command should be

```
mspyellow@BJ:~$ /usr/bin/sudo apt-get install apturl
```

Comment: umm.. after installing JDK 7 i added some thing at the end, the only reason why I did it, I was following a tutorial on how to install it. I later went back when and deleted the lines I added because I notices I had to put "usr/bin/". Is there a way that I can get rid of it and go back to how it was? or is the path correct? Also I thank you and appreciate for replying

Comment: @brayanestevez May I ask what exactly you have changed? And in which file? Normally, the PATH variable gets set in the file /etc/environment (You need sudo to edit this file). The file should look like `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"` or something similar. Did you edit this file? Maybe, you forgot a colon or a slash?

Comment: @brayanestevez: your comment would be [a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).  If the above answered your original question, just click the little grey **☑** under the "1" right now turning it into beautiful green...  **;-)**